# Problem finding the number of times the inequality is true

Tags: c++

Im having a math problem. The program consists out of 5 input variables (p,q,r,L,R) and 1 output.

Problem: A person has N number of chocolates. He wishes to share it to 3 persons. The first person would get N/p chocolates (if the fraction is 5.00, he gives 5 to the person, but if the fraction is 5.01 or so (you must ceil(L/p) to a higher number). He gives L/q chocolates to person #2 and L/r chocolates to person #3. If the number N changes from [L,R], how much times is it possible for him to successfully share the chocolates so that it never goes over his stocks. The condition that must be met is

( ceil(L/p) + ceil(L/q) + ceil(L/r)) <= N

The point is to count it as fast as possible. I tried to find the first succesful time the condition is met and then multiply it by the times it consists in R, but I couldn't find a way to do it in ~0.5 seconds.

An example (correct one):
Input: 2 3 7 9 14
Output: 2

The working version (But waaaay too sloow) is: 
The working version is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);


    int p,q,r;
    //unsigned long long int L,R;
    unsigned long long int L,R;
    int i=0;

    cin >> p;
    cin >> q;
    cin >> r;
    cin >> L;
    cin >> R;

    for (; L<=R; L++) {

        if(( ceil((long double)L/p)+ ceil((long double)L/q ) + ceil((long double)L/r) ) <= L) {
            i++;
        }
    }
    cout << i;
}
```

Input limitations are: 
1 <= a,b,c <= 10 
And 
1 <= X <= Y <= 10^18

Comment: Please post the results of your debugging session.  Which line or statement is causing the issue?  What are the actual variable values?  What are the expected values?

Comment: In your `while` loop, where does `R` change its value?

Comment: You've got truncation and sign issues with your `int j = Y/X`.  An `unsigned long long` may be a lot larger than an `int` (and not fit).  Also `Y/X` is an *unsigned* result, but you are placing into a `signed` variable.  Signed variables may have a smaller range than `unsigned`.

Comment: Where is `L` declared?  What is it's initial value?  Does it change it's value?  Where are `p`, `q` and `r`?

Comment: Voting to close, doesn't compile due to missing variables.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I've edited my code. 
The input should be:
3 4 5 1 1000000000000000000
The output should be:
999999999999999998

But the problem is that it is too slow. My limit to complete it is ~ 1 seconds. There must be some math overthere. Input limitations are:

1 <= a,b,c <= 10
And
1 <= X <= Y <= 10^18

Comment: Please edit your question and add additional info in it. Does it have to be `long double`? Can't you just `N / a + !!(N % a)`? Please don't use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`.  Just `#include <cmath>`

Comment: @KamilCuk No, it does not needs to be long double. It should be int

Comment: My hardware knowledge is very basic but if I check my CPU (2.7GHz) and if I assume (probably very poorly)  that it can therefore check 2.7G different values of  `L` it would still take roughly 10^10 seconds to complete... So your algorithm must be improved!!!! I would be happy to stand corrected...

Comment: @PinkFloyd yes, so there must a mathematical way to prove it only occurs a few times. It's both programming and math question

Comment: (frst hint) rewrite your condition as a+b+c<T (second hint) you don't need to start at L=0 (last hint, maybe the best) as you know the expected output shoud be 999999999999999998 out of   1000000000000000000, only 2 cases fails, probably within the first 20 numbers -just a wild guess- show that the inequality will always be true from a certain point on, then find them with your code...

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you should use the fact that, incrementing `L`, you also increment the remainder of the divisions `L/p`, `L/q` and `L/r`

So I suppose you can compute only three divisions and avoid divisions inside the loop.

I mean... instead of

```
for (; L<=R; L++) {

    if(( ceil((long double)L/p)+ ceil((long double)L/q ) + ceil((long double)L/r) ) <= L) {
        i++;
    }
}
```

you could write (caution: code tested only with 2, 3, 7, 9, 14)

```
auto dp = std::lldiv(L, p);
auto dq = std::lldiv(L, q);
auto dr = std::lldiv(L, r);

auto rp = dp.rem;
auto rq = dq.rem;
auto rr = dr.rem;

auto sum =   dp.quot + (rp ? 1ll : 0ll)
           + dq.quot + (rq ? 1ll : 0ll)
           + dr.quot + (rr ? 1ll : 0ll);

while ( L <= R )
 {
   if ( sum <= L++ )
      ++i ;

   if ( 1ll == ++rp )
      ++sum;
   else if ( p == rp )
      rp = 0ll;

   if ( 1ll == ++rq )
      ++sum;
   else if ( q == rq )
      rq = 0ll;

   if ( 1ll == ++rr )
      ++sum;
   else if ( r == rr )
      rr = 0ll;
 }
```

And, maybe, you can simplify a little the `if`-`else if` part.

Off Topic: I've used `long long` for all variables: `p`, `q`, `r`, `L`, `R` and `i`.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand  how to use this code correctly. I replaced it with the part you told me, but it says 'dp does not name a type' etc

Comment: @snickex - ehmm... sorry... are you using C++98?